# How to Populate the 3rd Dropdown in HTML Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem not knowing how to populate or create the 3rd box that will show the result on the 2nd box. What I'm trying to do is select the brand, then model then on 3rd box, it will show their model numbers.

```
<select name="device" id="device" onchange="changecat(this.value);">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="A">Apple</option>
  <option value="S">Samsung</option>
  <option value="L">LG</option>
  <option value="G">Google</option>
  </select>
  <select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  </select>
```

and here's the other code

```
var brandByCategory = {
  A: ["iPhone", "iPhone 3G", "iPhone 3GS", "iPhone 4"],
  S: ["Galaxy S3", "Galaxy S4", "Galaxy S5", "Galaxy S6"],
  L: ["G3", "G4", "G5", "G6", "G7"],
  G: ["Pixel", "Pixel XL", "Pixel 2", "Pixel 2 XL", "Pixel 3", "Pixel 3 XL", "Pixel 3A", "Pixel 3A XL", "Pixel 4", "Pixel 4 XL"]

}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in brandByCategory[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + brandByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any 3rd `select` box. plus it is working for second `select` box

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? The question is not clear

Comment: Where is model number? Do you need to extract from given data?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeBailey I have updated my question. Basically, I need result on the 3rd box, it could just be an input box but it will show the model number of the device in the 2nd box. Havent added the model numbers yet since I cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Foxseiz from where do you get model number?

Comment: I will just have to add them to the array manually.

Comment: @Foxseiz you may need to use array of objects in order to store the model number for the specific device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the model number with the device, I'd suggest you to use array of objects and add the model number as value to second drop down as shown below.

And from second dropdown, you can get the value and then display it wherever you want.

```js
var brandByCategory = {
    A: [{
        name: "iPhone",
        model: "10"
    }, {
        name: "iPhone 3G",
        model: "3G"
    }],
    S: [{
        name: "Galaxy S3",
        model: "S3"
    }, {
        name: "Galaxy S4",
        model: "S4"
    }]

}

function changecat(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var catOptions = "";
        for (categoryId in brandByCategory[value]) {
            catOptions += `<option value = "${brandByCategory[value][categoryId].model}">${brandByCategory[value][categoryId].name}</option>`;
        }
        document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
    }
}
var input = document.getElementById("modelNumber")

function populateValue(val) {
    input.value = val;
}
```

```html
<select name="device" id="device" onchange="changecat(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="A">Apple</option>
    <option value="S">Samsung</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category" onchange="populateValue(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="modelNumber" />
```

Comment: Hi George, sorry for the late response. Was reading on how to create an Array of objects and yes, this is exactly how I need it. Thank you very much.